# Multi tables with same schema, query design strategy?

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

I have an Oracle database with a dodgy design: many tables have same schema. They're pieces from a huge table, and time by time, new tables will be created with specific rows. Of course, I'm not authorized to access the huge table, only the small ones. How can I query against these tables, effectively?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a dodgy design or simply horizontal partitioning?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's no way to use a single prepared statement against multiple distinct tables, if that's what you mean.  Maybe you could make a view that's a union of all the tables...?

Comment: New tables are created by times, can you give me more details on this approach?

Comment: @vimvq, the union statement must explicitly list all the tables (or queries) of interest, so you'd have to alter the view each and every time tables get created, deleted, or renamed.  No decently performing way to query against a set of table that is not known at query-writing time (!), AFAIK (I'd be pretty surprised if one existed, though I _have_ been surprised sometimes in my life;-).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pipelined function that dynamically builds a SQL statement to select from all the relevant tables.

```
--Create tables.  They can be created at any time, but they have
--to follow some sort of naming convention
create table temp1(test1 number, test2 varchar2(100));
create table temp2(test1 number, test2 varchar2(100));
create table temp3(test1 number, test2 varchar2(100));


--Create a package that will return one result at a time from all the tables.
create or replace package query_tables is
  type output_rectype is record
  (
    test1 number
    ,test2 varchar2(100)
  );
  type output_rectype_table is table of output_rectype;
  function query return output_rectype_table pipelined;
end query_tables;
/


create or replace package body query_tables is
  function query return output_rectype_table pipelined is
    sql_statement varchar2(32767);
    output output_rectype;
    my_cursor sys_refcursor;
  begin
    --Build a select statment that combines all relevant tables
    for tables in (select table_name from user_tables where table_name like 'TEMP%') loop
      sql_statement := sql_statement || 'select * from '||tables.table_name||' union all ';
    end loop;
    --Remove the last 'union all'
    sql_statement := substr(sql_statement, 1, length(sql_statement) - 11);

    --Get one result at a time and return it
    open my_cursor for sql_statement;
    loop
      fetch my_cursor into output;
      exit when my_cursor%notfound;
      pipe row(output);
    end loop;
  end;
end query_tables;
/


--Insert some test data
insert into temp1 values(1, 'asdf');
insert into temp2 values(2, 'fgds');
insert into temp3 values(3, 'rewq');


--Display the results from all tables with one query
select * from table(query_tables.query);
```